# window.history.pushState is not pushing state and thus unable to retrieve in window.popstate event call back

Tags: javascript, html, history, pushstate, popstate

I am facing one problem, I am setting data in `history.pushState` api, like this:

```
history.pushState({ routeInfo: {abc:123, test:'test'} }, '', path);
```

And I am expecting same `routeInfo` object in my state when popstate is triggered for same url

```
window.onpopstate = (e) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.state.routeInfo)); // here routeInfo is undefined 
};
```

but `e.state` is not having `routeInfo` object, `e.state` is returning something different like below

```
state:
id:"0.6798624668897009_2"
user:undefined
```

Can you please let me know what is going wrong, why state is not being retained for a given url, and how to retrieve this? I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: It started working when i gave history.pushState two times i don't know why, this link helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363645/why-is-event-state-on-window-onpopstate-empty-when-pushing-with-same-location-hr

Comment: If I push two times ,when i hit back browser is updating same url , that is wrong again .. please help how to fix this.